# Trying a bfs style approach to solving how many islands are there

Tags: python

See edit at bottom

So I have an 2d array where 1's represents land and 0's represents water. It is considered an island if the land is surrounded by water (and the areas outside of the 2d array are considered surrounded by water) and its one landmass if the above below and left and right are land.

so for example :
Input:

```
grid = [

  ["1","1","0","0","0"],
  ["1","1","0","0","0"],
  ["0","0","1","0","0"],
  ["0","0","0","1","1"]
]
```

Output: 3

```
class Solution:
    def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        
        rows, cols = len(grid), len(grid[0])
        visited = set()
        amount_islands = 0

        def bfs(r,c):
            q = collections.deque() #.append .popleft
            visited.add((r,c))
            q.append([r,c])
            while q:
                a = q.popleft()
                r = a[0]
                c = a[1]
                if r-1  >= 0 :
                    if (r-1,c) not in visited:
                        q.append([r-1,c])
                        visited.add((r-1,c))
                if r+1 <= rows-1:
                    if (r+1,c) not in visited:
                        q.append([r+1,c])
                        visited.add((r+1,c))
                if c-1 >= 0:
                    if (r,c-1) not in visited:
                        q.append([r,c-1])
                        visited.add((r, c-1))
                if c+1 <= cols-1:
                    if (r,c+1) not in visited:
                        q.append([r,c+1])
                        visited.add((r,c+1))
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(cols):
                if grid[r][c] == "1" and (r,c) not in visited:
                    bfs(r,c)
                    amount_islands += 1
        return amount_islands
```

In my while statement, I pop the first thing in q, find the valid adjacements and then append that to the q and visited. However, I am not getting the results I expect. Any ideas on why this is?
I am pretty much adapting this implementation :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/

EDIT* okay I answered my own question. The geeksforgeeks methodology is solid as expected, the issue is that I did not check for if the up down left right values to add to the queue were land or water. I don't know how to close this question or mark as resolved so I think I will just have to leave it as is.

Comment: You can answer your `own` question

Answer (score 0):

The geeksforgeeks methodology is solid as expected, the issue is that I did not check for if the up down left right values to add to the queue were land or water.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).